# How can Google Apps Script setFormula set a formula to sheet cell containing variables

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My plan is to calculate how many days between 2 given dates by using function `DATEDIF` in Google Spreadsheet and the function must be from Google Apps Script. I can get it by below.

```
sheet.getRange(x,10).setFormula('datedif(K32,L32,"d")');
```

However, as the row is increasing by AppendRow whenever GAS calls spreadsheet so I tried to use variable x to get the last row. It makes me know where the target row is. My trouble is that I could not let setFormula to use variable as below, where `start` and `due` are A1Notation of the 2 given cells with date.

```
sheet.getRange(x,9).setFormula('datedif([start],[due],"d")');
```

MY code is as below.

```
   var x = sheet.getLastRow();
   
   sheet.getRange(x,11).setValue("2020/05/20");
   sheet.getRange(x,12).setValue("2020/07/21");
    
   start = sheet.getRange(x,11).getA1Notation();
   due = sheet.getRange(x,12).getA1Notation();  
    
   
  sheet.getRange(x,9).setFormula('datedif([start],[due],"d")');

  sheet.getRange(x,10).setFormula('datedif(K32,L32,"d")');
```

Comment: Why not use `ARRAYFORMULA`?

Comment: The question is how to set formula to sheet cell through GAS, I don't think formula itself maters.

Comment: How is the script called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

*You need to concatenate the cells' A1 notations into your string in `setFormula()`.*

#### Code Modification:

As of V8, you can use template literals inside Google Apps Script. You can do this as below:

```js
start = sheet.getRange(x,11).getA1Notation();
due = sheet.getRange(x,12).getA1Notation();  

sheet.getRange(x,9).setFormula(`datedif(${start},${due},"d")`);
```

#### References:

- [Template literals (Template strings) - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: It really works, but it encounter another question.

Comment: @LookForwardChuang I do not understand what you mean

Comment: It really works when I test by copying the link and directly post on https:// with some parameters for doGet(e) . But when I input doGet(e) parameters from MIT Inventor, it just shows the parameters from MIT Inventor, it does not show the setFormula seems like this code did not be excuted.

Comment: I have to retrieve this question because I had made a mistake. I have 2 GAS files and I got confused to use the "backup" GAS file. I've corrected the url from MIT Inventor.

Comment: @LookForwardChuang I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Please can you explain you last comment?

Comment: Sorry, the issue was fixed. I found I had made a mistake...and now I've corrected the fault.