# Modifying formula to work in appsscripts code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for some help on modifying an equation so that it works inside appsscript code.

Formula in GoogleSheets:
`=IF(HOME!T2:T<>"",TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(LEFT(HOME!T2:T,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(HOME!T2:T,"/","#",4))-1),"//strong[@data-e2e='video-views']")),"")`

Line in AppsScript:
`cell.setFormula("=IF(HOME!T2:T<>'',TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(LEFT(HOME!T2:T,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(HOME!T2:T,'/','#',4))-1),'//strong[@data-e2e='video-views']')),'')");`

Resulting error:
[image: error in appsscript]

Appreciate any help I can get with this!

Comment: @Rubén just made this correction, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, maybe my brain was just not functioning correctly. I have escaped the quotation marks within the String and hopefully it should work now:

`cell.setFormula("=IF(HOME!T2:T<>\"\",TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(LEFT(HOME!T2:T,FIND(\"#\",SUBSTITUTE(HOME!T2:T,\"/\",\"#\",4))-1),\"//strong[@data-e2e='video-views']\")),\"\")");`

Comment: Another option is to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/63517984/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62617854/1595451